# Testing API via newman

Tags: api, postman, newman

Hi there I am testing an API via postman, I want to automate my tests and have downloaded newman. Now the request I use in postman has been exported as a collection and is giving me a 404 via newman.... Any pointers much appreciated. IP address has been changed for obvious reasons.

```
{
"id": "11f345f7-9f12-58fb-099d-27f11233cee7",
"name": "GC",
"description": "",
"order": [
    "f7fe3f94-0dd2-6dba-05b9-29ae7e571ed9"
],
"folders": [],
"timestamp": 1446559540652,
"owner": "195242",
"remoteLink": "",
"public": false,
"requests": [
    {
        "id": "f7fe3f94-0dd2-6dba-05b9-29ae7e571ed9",
        "headers": "",
        "url": "http://218.24.201.144/cb/mobile/v1/residences/568288d0-71b6-11e5-ad9f-0242ac110908/lastAirQuality/rooms",
        "pathVariables": {},
        "preRequestScript": "",
        "method": "GET",
        "collectionId": "11f345f7-9f12-58fb-099d-27f11233cee7",
        "data": [],
        "dataMode": "params",
        "name": "http://218.24.201.144/cb/mobile/v1/residences/568288d0-71b6-11e5-ad9f-0242ac110908/lastAirQuality/rooms",
        "description": "",
        "descriptionFormat": "html",
        "time": 1446559548262,
        "version": 2,
        "responses": [],
        "tests": "",
        "currentHelper": "normal",
        "helperAttributes": {}
    }
]
```

}

this is the output I get in newman

```
    $ newman -c GC.json.postman_collection

Iteration 1 of 1
404 218ms http://218.24.201.144/cb/mobile/v1/residences/568288d0-71b6-11e5-ad9f-0242ac110908/lastAirQuality/rooms http://218.24.201.144/cb/mobile/v1/residences/568288d0-71b6-11e5-ad9f-0242ac110908/lastAirQuality/rooms

Summary:

Parent                      Pass Count   FailCount
-------------------------------------------------------------
Collection GC                        0           0

Total

                             0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tests set?

```
    var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    tests["Pass this case"] = data.id === 11f345f7-9f12-58fb-099d-27f11233cee7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `Tests` and don't forgot to update your json collection before testing.

Check this [#298](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/298)

Answer (score 0):

404 is means the resource you are looking in is not exist, or the system is unable to find the requested data, you can try using

```
$ newman run <path of you collection>
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install postman

npm install newman

npm install newman-reporter-html

https://github.com/shahing/api-automation-tests

run command in your directory : newman run test.js